# Cannot load svg in nrwl react workspace

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nrwl-nx

I've been trying nrwl tool to create workspace. I've created one with

```sh
npm init nx-workspace
```

then moved the app created with  `create-react-app --typescript` into that workspace.

1. I get: Cannot find module './logo.svg'.ts(2307)
2. fixed by (got after ejecting react-app

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

and then I got (I assume it's webpack complaining)

```
ERROR in ./orig/logo.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
```

I'd love to have same experience when create-react-app handles all webpack transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

1. add to /angular.json

```
{
 ...,
 "projects": {
   ...,
   "projectName": {
     ...,
     "architect": {
       ...,
       "build": {
         "options": {
           "webpackConfig": "apps/pathToProject/webpack.config.js",
           ...,
...
```

2. /webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = (config, context) => {
    const { module } = config;

    module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader']
    });

    return { ...config, module };
};
```

3. jest config
   https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files

(added **mocks**/fileMock.js)

```js
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

4. /jest.config:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  },
  ...
};
```